# Cannot import .CSV product list to Shopify

Tags: csv, validation, dataset, shopify, libreoffice-calc

I Exported my dataset to CSV format,  bulk edited some data, and cannot import it after that, my db is almost empty now.

---

I had a tiny data set on my Shopify webshop with ca. 40 items.

I exported it into CSV format to bulk correct some typo's, and html descriptions. After the corrections, I imported it back, but my database contained duplicated entries (with the new corrected versions)...and... as I wanted to fix that I deleted all of my entries, made a sample product as a starting point of a new db but I cannot import my CSV file anymore. I see a success message but no entries after that (except the sample product's I created manually).

Did I misformat it?
The format I used is utf-8, en-US, comma separated.

Comment: After importing products you should receive an email from Shopify that will tell you how many products got imported and will also tell you which didn't get imported and what the errors were.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that too lately, but it's solved. The problem was when I cleared the items their images were also deleted, but the image url entries remained in the CSV file and this threw an error.

Comment: Try this free [product CSV import app](https://apps.shopify.com/storerobo-import-export-app)